# Update size of blocks from process modeling library during model run

Tags: anylogic

I have a simple model I have built using the process modeling library in AnyLogic. Entities sit in the first delay block for the specified amount of time before passing to the next. See image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPRrJ.png)

When the size() of the first delay block exceeds 90 entities I would like to update the number of entities in both blocks by -10 and +10 respectively. Essentially, I want to push 10 from the first to the second.

This would replicate a real life process of a person deciding 10 entities don't need to wait in the first delay and are fine to skip to the next.

I have no problem with setting up an event which triggers when the size hits 90.

I know that I could use a source block to generate the 10 into the second block, but I couldn't find a way to push entities into a sink.

I also tried (as a bit of a longshot) using Block1.size() = Block1.size()+10 - this doesn't make the compiler very happy.

I found this documentation re adding or removing agents from a population (https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/dynamic-creation-and-destruction.html) but I don't require any agents with custom parameters so for simplicity I would like to keep working in the Main and would rather not create a population of agents.

Is there a way to update the sizes of blocks as I have specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Block1.size()>90){
    List <Agent> agentsInDelay=findAll(Block1,a->true).subList(0,10);
    for(Agent a : agentsInDelay){
        Block1.stopDelay(a);
    }
}
```